# NHibernate and Oracle connect through Windows Authenication

Tags: windows, oracle, nhibernate

How do I use Windows Authentication to connect to an Oracle database?

Currently, I just use an Oracle Username and password, however, a requirement is to give the user on install the option of selecting Windows Authentication since we offer the same as SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES entry in SQLNET.ORA to this:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

As well, you will need to setup the accounts in Oracle to match the Windows accounts. Have a look at http://www.dba-oracle.com/bk_sqlnet_authentication_services.htm for more details.